# Laravel AJAX post returning 500 error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

**EDIT**

Thanks for the ideas - I was going crazy trying to figure out how to debug this issue. I ended up just trying to work through my original intent for this post call and the data is updating just fine in my DB. I left everything the same in my HTML, AJAX, and route, but updated my controller.

The 500 error seems like it was coming from the fact that I was trying to dd($request) in my controller, which I just don't understand. I can dd($request) on a GET request but I can't on a POST? Seems crazy to me. I guess that's a new question all together..

---

I'm trying to make an AJAX post in Laravel with a select element's value. I've read several posts related to 500 errors on AJAX posts and have done what I can to fix the issue but I can't figure out what is wrong. Most people point out the csrf_token, and to check the laravel.log for issues, but I've inserted the csrf_token and checked my logs - nothing logs when I test out my code at this point in the browser. Here's what I have:

HTML

```
    <!-- I have this placed in the head -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> 

    <!-- This table displays each task with a select dropdown for the user to mark their status -->
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($tasks as $task)
      <tr class="course-row">
        <td>{{ $task->title }}</td>
        <td>{{ $task->description }}</td>
        <td>
          <select id="select-status-{{ $task->id }}" class="select-status" data-task-id="{{ $task->id }}">
            <option value="0">Incomplete</option>
            <option value="1">In Progress</option>
            <option value="2">Complete</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
```

JQUERY / AJAX

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
    });

    $('.select-status').change(function() {
      var $taskId = $(this).attr('data-task-id');
      var $status = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/taskstatus/'+$taskId,
        data: {taskId:$taskId, status:$status}
      });
    });
  });
```

ROUTE

```
Route::post('/taskstatus/{id}', 'StatusController@markTask');
```

CONTROLLER METHOD

```
public function markTask(Request $request)
    {
       dd($request);
    }
```

I originally had a form using the same url, but just using a form action to make the post request.. but the user will have tons of these selections to make on a page and I can't have the page reloading so I need to use AJAX. Ultimately, the users selections will update a pivot table value, and will determine the status of the subsequent tasks. At this point I'm just trying to debug and simply dd my request, but I'm at a standstill because of this 500 error. Any suggestions?

Comment: first try to debug that your route works directly from browser - so change your route from POST to GET and type full link in browser i see what will be the resutl

Comment: Ok, so I changed my route to test that and it's dd-ing the request. I also popped in an echo message just to make sure, and it's responding properly

Comment: add `$.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
    });` this part within `$('.select-status').change(function() { ` section

Comment: next step: change back your rote from GET to POST. And next step - go to chrome console - network tab, and put screenshow what your POST request looks like